# How to append with loop in python

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I have been searching for hours. I have 190 columns of pivot table to loop on my script
I have this script:

```
corr = pg.pairwise_corr(df_pvt, columns=[[df_pvt.columns[0]], list(df_pvt.columns)], method='pearson')[['X','Y','r']]
```

this provide output:

```
                                          X  ...      r
0    CORSEC_Mainstream Media_Negative Count  ...  1.000
1    CORSEC_Mainstream Media_Negative Count  ...  0.960
2    CORSEC_Mainstream Media_Negative Count  ... -0.203
3    CORSEC_Mainstream Media_Negative Count  ... -0.446
4    CORSEC_Mainstream Media_Negative Count  ...  0.488
..                                      ...  ...    ...
179  CORSEC_Mainstream Media_Negative Count  ... -0.483
180  CORSEC_Mainstream Media_Negative Count  ... -0.487
181  CORSEC_Mainstream Media_Negative Count  ...  0.145
182  CORSEC_Mainstream Media_Negative Count  ...  0.128
183  CORSEC_Mainstream Media_Negative Count  ...  0.520

[184 rows x 3 columns]
```

I want to append 189 other columns to my script,
but this script keep providing 2 appended variables and keep replacing until the 189th variables

```
for var in list(range(1,189)):
    corr_all = corr.append(pg.pairwise_corr(df_pvt, columns=[[df_pvt.columns[var]], list(df_pvt.columns)], method='pearson')[['X','Y','r']])
    print(corr_all)
```

Any advice?

Edit:

Its work like this:

```
corr = pg.pairwise_corr(df_pvt, columns=[[df_pvt.columns[0]], list(df_pvt.columns)], method='pearson')[['X','Y','r']]
corr_1 = corr.append(pg.pairwise_corr(df_pvt, columns=[[df_pvt.columns[1]], list(df_pvt.columns)], method='pearson')[['X','Y','r']])
corr_2 = corr_1.append(pg.pairwise_corr(df_pvt, columns=[[df_pvt.columns[2]], list(df_pvt.columns)], method='pearson')[['X','Y','r']])
```

But how I loop it until the corr_189?

Answer (score 1):

You can try making 189 lists of values (Pearson coefficients) for each of your 189 columns, and **then** concatenate the columns with " df_final " which would be the dataframe containing all the 190 columns :

```
corr = pd.DataFrame(corr)
df_final = pd.DataFrame()

for k in range(189):
    list_Pearson_k = 'formula to compute a list of pearson values'                    
    df_list_k = pd.DataFrame(list_Pearson_k)
    df_final = pd.concat([corr,df_list_k ], axis = 1)
```

Comment: Sorry is that mean I need to make 189 rows of script to get 189 lists?

Comment: Fortunately no! I meant that you can do a loop, like in my answer, and that you could concatenate the column of pearson values at each iteration like this :            corr = pd.DataFrame(corr)
for k in range(189):
    list_Pearson_k = 'formula to compute a list of pearson values'                    
    df_list_k = pd.DataFrame(list_Pearson_k)
    df_final = pd.concat([corr,df_list_k ], axis = 1)                                                     
This way you can get a df_final with your 190 columns of pearson values. If you want I can try to implement it but only in a few hours!

Comment: I changed my answer you can check that : instead of 'formula to compute a list of pearson values'  you can put " pg.pairwise_corr(df_pvt, columns=[[df_pvt.columns[2]], list(df_pvt.columns)], method='pearson')[['X','Y','r']]" but I didn't try to run it

Answer (score 0):

Python `list` `append` method returns `None`.

Change your code to this:-

```
corr_all = []
for var in range(1,189):
    corr_all.append(pg.pairwise_corr(df_pvt, columns=[[df_pvt.columns[var]], list(df_pvt.columns)], method='pearson')[['X','Y','r']])
    print(corr_all)
```

This should help.

Comment: `list(range(1, 189))` is a bit silly, because `range()` gives you an in-order iterable and then that's turned into a list which.... you iterate over. Remove the call to `list()` and the solution is more pythonic.

Comment: @Dhaval Taunk Thanks but Its still provide 2 columns combination at the end, how to generate all combination in 1 result?

Comment: its work with this, but I should make like 189 rows like this. How to loop this? `corr = pg.pairwise_corr(df_pvt, columns=[[df_pvt.columns[0]], list(df_pvt.columns)], method='pearson')[['X','Y','r']]
corr_1 = corr.append(pg.pairwise_corr(df_pvt, columns=[[df_pvt.columns[1]], list(df_pvt.columns)], method='pearson')[['X','Y','r']])
corr_2 = corr_1.append(pg.pairwise_corr(df_pvt, columns=[[df_pvt.columns[2]], list(df_pvt.columns)], method='pearson')[['X','Y','r']])
`

Comment: @Irwan, sorry I didn't understand your question. Can you please explain properly?